# Elasticsearch Remove duplicate results if greater than some value

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have news articles form multiple sources saved and each source have different category I need to write a query which will reverse time sort the article in chunks of 15 at a time also I don't need more than 3 articles from a particular source I am using the below query but the results are wrong can any one tell me what am I doing wrong.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "category": "Digital"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "type": "Local"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "source.keyword",
    "max_concurrent_group_searches": 3
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "pub_date": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what is your mapping?